# GBinding update timing?

Tags: gtk3, gobject

I connected a property of my GtkApplication with a GtkEntry field in my Preference dialog through g_object_bind_property. Works like a charm.

However, it works a little too well, in that each and every character added/deleted/changed in the GtkEntry is reflected in the corresponding GtkApplication property. I would like this update to happen only the GtkField is activated by the user pressing . Is there any way to tweak the timing of the binding, or should I just handle the activate signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think there is a way to make `GObject` property bindings conditional on a signal or on the value of a property. I think you need to handle the `activate` signal manually, as you suspected.